# Reporting Services - Convert 2008 Report Format to the 2005 Format

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Is there any way to convert the 2008 Report format back to a 2005 format?
I don't think I got prompted about my upgrading my reports and now I think they are in the new format. Any way to save my changes and go back a version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to go from 2005 to 2000. I would assume this is true still.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143747.aspx  Hopefully you followed the directions there and backed up the reportserver database.  Restore that to a test environment and you can recover your reports.

I would recommend RSScripter to anyone working with reporting services, btw.

Comment: + 1 and answer. Thanks, I was able to recover the project and make changes from an email luckily. So what is good about RSScripter?

Comment: RSScripter lets you move masses of reports around, with included subscription info. You could restore your install and then script your report .rdl files to your workstation.  

You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to go from 2008 back to 2005 by manually editing the XML. While this is not the easiest thing to do a simple program that uses RegEx to pattern match the old xml with the new could be written in about an hour.

Another option is to just re-create the reports in 2005, taking the queries from the current rdl file.

Comment: Whats the RegEx your using for match?  And what are you replacing with?